# Any free version of SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Is there a free version of SQL Server where one can practice or any other tool which checks correct SQL Server syntax?

I would like an offline one.

I am expecting something like OracleXE server.

Comment: The answer is SQL Server Express, which is easy to find on the Microsoft web site (or through Google).  However, this is not appropriate for Stack Overflow because it is asking about an off-site resource.

Comment: thanks ..i would try to avoid not appropriate questions in future

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you are looking for is SQL Express Edition. It is the free version with limitations.

Link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-platform/sql-server-editions-express

If you want all the features of SQL Server Enterprise edition to test then you need Developer Edition.

https://www.infoq.com/news/2016/06/SQL-Developer-Free

**Edit:**
To marc_s point here is the blog post from MSFT about MSSQL Developer Edition being free: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2016/03/31/microsoft-sql-server-developer-edition-is-now-free/

All you need to do is sign up for the "Dev Essentials" (Free):

https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-dev-essentials-vs

Comment: And as of mid 2016, the **Developer Edition** (for SQL Server 2014 / 2016) is now also freely available: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2016/03/31/microsoft-sql-server-developer-edition-is-now-free/